# how to poll a backend api periodically on page load with vue resource?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

After submitting a form to an api, I have a loading page rendered that needs to check every 1 second with a timeout of 60 seconds if the form data has been updated and display the status. Is there a way to keep retrying the ajax request and set time intervals and timeouts using vue-resource options? In their [documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md) they have a timeout option but no interval. Here is what I have so far:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="location === 'updated'">Location Updated!</div>
  <div v-if="location === 'error'">Update failed, check back later!</div>
  <div v-if="location === 'pending'">Loading...</div>
</template>

<script>
 ...

 data: function() {
   return { orderStatus: 'pending' }
 }

 ready: function() {
   this.$http.get('/location/12', { timeout: 60000, interval: 1000 } ).then((response) => {
        this.orderStatus = response.body.order_status
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `setInterval` or `setTimeout`?

Comment: @BenM I want both

Answer (score 0):

Web socket should be the ideal answer.

But if your goal is to see if form data has been updated, you can do polling these ways

Simple without Deferred

```
(function poll(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Setup the next poll recursively if order status is not updated
        if (orderStatus not update)
            poll()
        else
            display order status
      }, dataType: "json"});
  }, 30000);
})();
```

With Deferred:

```
// The polling function
function poll(fn, timeout, interval) {
    var dfd = new Deferred();
    var endTime = Number(new Date()) + (timeout || 2000);
    interval = interval || 100;

    (function p() {
            // If the condition is met, we're done! 
            if(fn()) {
                dfd.resolve();
            }
            // If the condition isn't met but the timeout hasn't elapsed, go again
            else if (Number(new Date()) < endTime) {
                setTimeout(p, interval);
            }
            // Didn't match and too much time, reject!
            else {
                dfd.reject(new Error('timed out for ' + fn + ': ' + arguments));
            }
    })();

    return dfd.promise;
}

// Usage:  ensure order status is updated
poll(function() {
    return response.body.order_status == "updated";
}, 2000, 150);
```